# Provision device using x509 from softHSMv2

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I want to provision a device using x509 security. The x509 certificate and private key are saved on an HSM. The private key cannot leave the HSM.

Ideally I'd like to pass the PKCS11 URI for both objects when creating the x509 object for transport.

```
  const deviceCert: X509 = {
   cert: cert,
   clientCertEngine: "pkcs11",
   keyFile: 'pkcs11:object=privateKey;type=private?pin-value=1234',
  };

  const securityClient = new X509Security(this.registrationId, deviceCert);
  this.provisioningClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.create(
    this.provisioningHost,
    this.idScopeOperator,
    new ProvisioningTransport(),
    securityClient
  );
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How do I provision an Azure IoT SDK Device (Node.js) using x509 from an HSM without the private key leaving the HSM?